# Modificar los valores de un array

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, objeto

Tengo los siguientes arrays:

```
    var autos= [{
    "id_Modelo": 1,
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
},{
    "id_Modelo": 2,
    "Referencia": "corola 2",
    "Precio": 45221
},{
    "id_Modelo": 3,
    "Referencia": "chevrolet 9",
    "Precio": 5090
}];

var autos_identificador= [{
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "id_Modelo": 3,
},{
    "Modelo": "corola",
    "id_Modelo": 2,
},{
    "Modelo": "chevrolet",
    "id_Modelo": 1,
}];
```

Pueden haber "n" autos con diferente Referencia y Precio, pero solo van a existir el Modelo y el id_Modelo que estan en el array de autos_identificador.

Con el siguiente codigo, obtengo todos los id_Modelo del array de autos

```
var idModelos = autos.map((item) => item.id_Modelo)
```

Y luego (como el id_Modelo se repetira en muchos autos), desecho  los repetidos y obtengo los que no se repiten, con el siguiente codigo.

```
const unicos = new Set(idModelos); //Quito todos repetidos del array
const array_de_unicos = Array.from(unicos) //Transformo el Set en un array normal
```

Necesito ayuda en hacer un nuevo array, donde asigne el nombre de su id al campo 'Modelo' por ejemplo:

```
var autos= [{
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "Precio": 73710
},{
    "Modelo": "corola",
    "Precio": 45221
},{
    "Modelo": "chevrolet",
    "Precio": 5090
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Te vale enlazar los dos arrays de una, sin los pasos intermedios que indicas?

Por ejemplo, en el código de abajo, el map del final, por cada auto en `autos`, encuentra el auto en `autos_identificador` que tenga el mismo `id_Modelo`, luego junta el precio con el modelo.

Puesto que la función [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) devuelve `undefined` si no se encuentra un elemento que encaje, en el return del map he puesto `encontrado?.Modelo` para evitar errores (el interrogante ahí en medio se llama ["encadenamiento opcional"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)).

Luego con `filter` quito todos los casos en los que no se haya encontrado un elemento común entre `autos` y `autos_identificador`.

```js
const autos = [ {
    "id_Modelo": 1,
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
  }, {
    "id_Modelo": 2,
    "Referencia": "corola 2",
    "Precio": 45221
  }, {
    "id_Modelo": 3,
    "Referencia": "chevrolet 9",
    "Precio": 5090
  },{
    "id_Modelo": 4,
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
  } ];

const autos_identificador = [ {
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "id_Modelo": 3,
  }, {
    "Modelo": "corola",
    "id_Modelo": 2,
  }, {
    "Modelo": "chevrolet",
    "id_Modelo": 1,
  } ];

const array_final = autos.map(auto => {
  const encontrado = autos_identificador.find(buscando => buscando.id_Modelo === auto.id_Modelo);
  
  return { Precio: auto.Precio, Modelo: encontrado?.Modelo };
}).filter(auto => auto.Modelo);
console.log(array_final);
```

---

Si prefieres hacerlo con tu array `array_de_unicos`:

```js
var autos = [ {
    "id_Modelo": 1,
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
  }, {
    "id_Modelo": 2,
    "Referencia": "corola 2",
    "Precio": 45221
  }, {
    "id_Modelo": 3,
    "Referencia": "chevrolet 9",
    "Precio": 5090
} ];

var autos_identificador = [ {
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "id_Modelo": 3,
  }, {
    "Modelo": "corola",
    "id_Modelo": 2,
  }, {
    "Modelo": "chevrolet",
    "id_Modelo": 1,
} ];

const idModelos = autos.map((item) => item.id_Modelo) 
const unicos = new Set(idModelos);
const array_de_unicos = Array.from(unicos);

const array_final = array_de_unicos.map(id => {
  const precio = autos.find(auto => auto.id_Modelo === id)?.Precio;
  const modelo = autos_identificador.find(auto => auto.id_Modelo === id)?.Modelo;
  
  return { Modelo: modelo, Precio: precio };
}).filter(elemento => elemento.Modelo && elemento.Precio);

console.log(array_final);
```

Comment: Me sirvio! solo una pregunta de novato, donde puedo investigar el uso de ? que pones, que dices que es por si existen errores, (?.Precio), ya que no tengo conocimiento de su funcionamiento o uso

Comment: @Geracros aquí tienes documentación, se llama "Encadenamiento opcional": https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining